# Unable to install ROracle package for DB connectivity with R

Tags: r

I am building a R Shiny app. I want to fetch data directly from my database for visualization, but when I am trying to install package using install.packages('ROracle_1.2-1') I am getting an error :

> install.packages('ROracle_1.3-1 (2).tar.gz') Warning in install.packages :   package ‘ROracle_1.3-1 (2).tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)

Please help!!!

Comment: Usually try install packages without the version number.  `install.packages('ROracle')` should work for you, or do you get an error also?

Comment: I followed the link - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL
Still getting the below error -

* installing *source* package 'ROracle' ...
** package 'ROracle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in system("sh ./configure.win") : 'sh' not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'ROracle'
* removing 'C:/Users/UTK17815/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library/ROracle'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ROracle’ had non-zero exit status

Any clue?

Comment: Hard to debug from here. What is the error message when doing `install.packages('ROracle')` . Your post pointed to a version problem, but it seem more severe.

Comment: The command I am running now is install.packages("ROracle-1.3.1",repos = NULL, type = "source")
The error I am getting is 
> install.packages("ROracle-1.3.1",repos = NULL, type = "source")
* installing *binary* package 'ROracle' ...
Warning in system(paste("cp -R .", shQuote(instdir), "|| (", TAR, "cd - .| (cd",  :
  'cp' not found
ERROR: installing binary package failed
* removing 'C:/Users/UTK17815/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library/ROracle'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ROracle-1.3.1’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Hi, again: What is the error message when doing just `install.packages('ROracle')`? Without any addition.

Comment: The installation instructions for compiling ROracle from source assume that you have _also_ installed all the necessary software you need to actually compile R packages. On Windows, this means installing Rtools. That is why you're getting errors about not finding "sh"; either it isn't installed with Rtools, or in the process your environment variables aren't correct.